# Perguntas sobre LaTeX

Tags: latex

Minha experiência de 2 dias escrevendo essa linguagem de marcação me deu a entender até o momento ser certamente muito limitada em vários apectos, apesar de eu não conhecer e saber me expandir diretamente com os recursos oferecidos. Pois então me veio as seguintes dúvidas que procurei e não encontrei especificamente, somente de modo geral.
Sei que talves não seja o lugar correto mas vamos lá;

1) Os elementos do LaTeX por exemplo (sumário) são editáveis ? por exemplo, eu posso mudar o nome sumário e colocar Índice ? ou trocar a numeração por algarismos romanos?

2) A troca de fonte é facil ou precisa instalar pacotes ? por exemplo, eu quero utilizar a Fonte Times New Roman em um parágrafo (no linux não tem), então como eu posso utilizar?

3) 10pt, 11pt e 12pt são os padrões, não existe 13pt ? ou maiores tamanhos de fontes ?

4) existem Sub section, subsubsection, e sub paragraph, porem e se eu quiser mais de 5 elementos hierárquicos ?

5) existe algum editor de texto igual o word que já monta a estrutura em código do LaTeX ?

Comment: O SOPT é mais liberal em relação ao que pode ser postado e acho que Latex pode. Dito isso, se não for problema fazer a pergunta em inglês no [Latex StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) você pode obter excelentes respostas.

Comment: Vou sim dar uma olhada,muito Obrigado, grande abraço !.

Comment: O SOPT já tem várias perguntas de [tag:latex]. Não é questão meramente de ser liberal - independentemente do propósito de uso, trata-se de uma linguagem compilada e aceita como no escopo do site. Naturalmente, é sempre bom lembrar que há um site específico em inglês, como citado pelo colega @hugomg. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1) Os elementos do LaTeX por exemplo (sumário) são editáveis ? por exemplo, eu posso mudar o nome sumário e colocar Índice ? ou trocar a numeração por algarismos romanos?

O TeX é extremamente flexível. Se você estiver usando algum template pronto (como o que eles mandam usar na minha universidade) algumas coisas podem ser difíceis de alterar mas em geral dá pra fazer quase tudo se você estiver disposto a dar uma fuçada.

> 2) A troca de fonte é facil ou precisa instalar pacotes ? por exemplo, eu quero utilizar a Fonte Times New Roman em um parágrafo (no linux não tem), então como eu posso utilizar?

Dá pra trocar a fonte mas acredito que precise instalar algum pacote sim.

> 3) 10pt, 11pt e 12pt são os padrões, não existe 13pt ? ou maiores tamanhos de fontes ?

Pra falar a verdade nunca mudei o tamanho da letra. Usar o padrão deixa o seu documento mais parecido com o dos outros.

Mas imagino que seja só uma questão de instalar algum pacote que está faltando ou usar uma implementação do latex com suporte a fontes de tamanho variável.

> 4) existem Sub section, subsubsection, e sub paragraph, porem e se eu quiser mais de 5 elementos hierárquicos ?

Subdivisões abaixo de subparagraph são muito específicas. Se você chegar a esse ponto é um sinal que alguma das suas sessões merece ser promovida a um capítulo :)

> 5) existe algum editor de texto igual o word que já monta a estrutura em código do LaTeX ?

O único editor de texto que conheço com uma cara mais "what you see is what you get" é o LyX. Se você só precisar de um "IDE pra Latex" com atalhos para inserir fórmulas, listas, etc aí tem outros como o Texmaker.

Comment: gênio. gostei da 4! vou procurar saber sobre Latex StackExchange, muito obrigado, grande abraço !.

Answer (score 7):

> 1) Os elementos do LaTeX por exemplo (sumário) são editáveis ? por
>   exemplo, eu posso mudar o nome sumário e colocar Índice ? ou trocar a
>   numeração por algarismos romanos?

Sim. Basta redefinir os comandos (dentro da seção do documento) com o comando `\renewcommand\elemento{novo nome para o elemento}`, onde `\elemento` é um dos comandos a seguir ([a fonte é esta resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3125241/2896619)):

- Resumo: `\abstractname`
- Apêndice: `\appendixname`
- Bibliografia: `\bibname`
- Capítulo: `\chaptername`
- Conteúdo: `\contentsname`
- Índice: `\indexname`
- Lista de Figuras: `\listfigurename`
- Lista de Tabelas: `\listtablename`
- Parte: `\partname`
- Referências: `\refname`

Por exemplo:

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{Capítulo bem Capitulado}
```

> 2) A troca de fonte é facil ou precisa instalar pacotes ? por exemplo,
>   eu quero utilizar a Fonte Times New Roman em um parágrafo (no linux
>   não tem), então como eu posso utilizar?

É fácil trocar as famílias de fontes nativas do LaTeX com o comando `\fontfamily` dentro de um escopo (no exemplo abaixo, as chaves). Há outros comandos, como `\fontsize` e `\textcolor` (mais detalhes, em inglês, [nesta página](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/latex_advanced/node17.html)). Por exemplo:

```
{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{18}{10}\selectfont
    Escreva todos os seus documentos com a fonte Helvética tamanho 18pt!
}
```

Eu acredito que o LaTeX não tenha o Times New Roman nativamente, mas pelo que eu sei dá pra usar o Times Roman com o [pacote pslatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pslatex). Vale a pergunta lá no [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) como sugerido em comentários.

> 3) 10pt, 11pt e 12pt são os padrões, não existe 13pt ? ou maiores
>   tamanhos de fontes ?

Sim, como ilustrado no exemplo anterior, usando o comando `\fontsize`.

> 4) existem Sub section, subsubsection, e sub paragraph, porem e se eu
>   quiser mais de 5 elementos hierárquicos ?

Existem os comandos `\section`, `\subsection` e `\subsubsection`. Se você tiver que dividir além disso, siga o conselho do colega @hugomg e pense em dividir em capítulos.

> 5) existe algum editor de texto igual o word que já monta a estrutura
>   em código do LaTeX ?

Eu cheguei a responder que existe o [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), como o colega @hugomg também citou, mas só depois percebi que você queria um editor [WYSIWYG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG). Nesse caso, eu desconheço. Acho que não deve ser uma ideia muito popular, pois o princípio do Tex/LaTeX é justamente não se preocupar com a formatação e sim com o conteúdo.

**P.S.: Exemplo funcional completo (também no [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ybcqxssysgmc)):**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}

% PERGUINTA 1 ---------------------
\renewcommand\chaptername{Capítulo bem Capitulado}
% ---------------------------------

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Introdução}

\section{Motivação}

Este trabalho tem várias motivações.

\subsection{Primeira Motivação}

Ganhar muito dinheiro!

\subsection{Segunda Motivação}

Ganhar ainda mais dinheiro!

\chapter{Realização do Trabalho}

\section{Passos}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Ter uma ideia brilhante!
\item Arrumar alguém com dinheiro pra investir na ideia brilhante!
\item Implementar a ideia brilhante!
\item Colher os louros do sucesso!

\end{enumerate}

E mais:

% PERGUINTA 2 ---------------------
{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{18}{10}\selectfont
Escreva todos os seus documentos com a fonte Helvética tamanho 18pt!
}
% ---------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Na pergunta está referindo o LaTeX como uma linguagem de marcação, isso está correto? Não seria uma linguagem de programação? Seguindo como base os conceitos da Máquina de Turing acredito que seria de programação mas mal conheço a linguagem, então não tenho certeza

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Olha, eu não sei dizer de verdade. Mas eu diria que ela é essencialmente uma linguagem de marcação pela *intenção de uso*. Dá pra programar coisas mais robustas nela? Até dá (de fato, ela também tem comandos de decisão e repetição de fluxo), mas é tão mais difícil (e pouco prático e intuitivo) usá-la pra isso que eu acho que faz mais sentido pensar no LaTeX como uma linguagem de marcação mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

## Uma resposta um pouco  *opinioned*:

Em linux, instala logo um LaTeX completo, texworks, pandoc.

Para arrancar com o LaTeX vale tudo.

Mas depois das primeiras experiências, o que queremos é:

- concentar (só) no conteúdo.
- não dispersar com  as mariquices -- (se o deixarmos, o tex mormalmente acerta!).

A vantagem do LaTeX é permitir-nos pensar em conceitos e não em aspecto.

1. ...fontes -- ao escrever um texto **não queremos saber de fontes** (se vier a ser crítico, depois juntaremos um `\usepackage...` que acerte esses detalhes)
2. ...tamanhos de letra -- **não queremos estar a detalhar tamanhos** (se vier a ser crítico, poderemos escolher um "factor multiplicativo" que entra como parametro no `\documentclass[]{...}`)
3. ...editor de texto igual o word -- existe mas **ficas muito melhor servido com sistemas que não sejam WYSIWYG** como o `texworks` que permitem ver a marcação
   dos conceitos e não distraem com o aspecto final.
4. ...ser certamente muito limitada em vários apectos -- **não concordo!** -- para ter uma ideia do que é o LaTeX, espreita no CTAN (comprehensive tex archive network)   (começa pelos pacotes da letra A https://www.ctan.org/pkg/:A)

Ou então experimenta o seguinte LaTeX (descrever conceitos, e a ferramenta trata do resto):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}

\setchessboard{setpieces= {Ke1, qa1, ke3} }
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]